# Explain the phrase "都不嫌多"

Tags: translation, meaning, phrase

Could you please explain how to make sense of "都不嫌多". How is the meaning composed from the characters. I cannot make the connection between the literal translation of "all not suspicion many" and actual translation "never too much".

Or maybe I should not even try?

The entire sentence:

怎么爱你都不嫌多
= I can't love you more
= However I love you, it’s never too much
= I can never love you too much

from the song 小苹果.

Comment: 怎么 ... 都 ... is a structure.

Answer (score 4):

> I cannot make the connection between the literal translation of "all not suspicion many" and actual translation "never too much".

The literal translation of `都` and `嫌` seems not exact, especially `嫌` doesn't mean `suspicion` here.

[都](http://dict.so.163.com/w/eng/%E9%83%BD/#keyfrom=dict2.index)

> 3.（表示强调） even:
>
> ```
> He didn't even look at it.
> 他连看都不看它一眼。
>
> Even a child knows all this.
> 这种事连小孩都知道。
> ```

[嫌](http://dict.so.163.com/w/%E5%AB%8C/#keyfrom=dict2.top)

> 动词
>    （厌恶; 不满意） dislike; mind; complain of:
>
> ```
> get oneself disliked;
> 讨人嫌
>
> not want to take the trouble; think it troublesome;
> 嫌麻烦
>
> Everybody disliked him because of his hot temper.
> 大家都嫌他脾气太急。
>
> You don't mind us smoking here, do you?
> 你不嫌我们在这里抽烟吧?
>
> She always complains of the food.
> 她常常嫌菜不好吃。
>
> The article is good in content, only it's a bit wordy.
> 这篇文章内容不错， 只是文字略嫌罗唆。
> ```

Then `怎么爱你都不嫌多` could be literally translated as `However I love you (I) won't even mind (it's) much`.

Could you make the connection now?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you need a few more examples of that `嫌`。

```
我男朋友嫌我薪水太少，所以和我分手了。
My boyfriend thinks my income is not enough so he broke up with me.

他不願僱用我們，因為他嫌我們兩個太懶散。
He didn't hire us, because he thinks we are too lazy.

主管嫌某個同事太吵，把他趕出了會議室。
My boss thinks one of my colleague is too noisy, so she kicked him out of the meeting room.

你不嫌麻煩，我都嫌麻煩了。
Though you don't think it troublesome, I really do think it is troublesome.

你是嫌事情還不夠多嗎！
Do you think we are available all day and we don't have things to do?

他嫌我矮。
He thinks I'm too short.

我超愛糖果，快給我糖果，一點也不嫌多。
I love candy very much. Give me candy! I will never feel enough.

我是工作狂，超愛工作，快分派任務給我，我絕不嫌多。
I'm a workaholic and I love work so much. Just assign tasks to me, I will never think it's too much.

錢是怎樣都不嫌多的。
You will never think you have too much money.
```

In brief, `嫌`=`think (most of the time in a dislike or negative way)`.

`怎么爱你都不嫌多` = `I will love you, and I will never(怎么...都不) think(嫌) my love for you is too much.`